# How to process this CSV and analyze this data?

Tags: python-3.x

I am given a csv that looks like this:

```
Jason,Bourne,1234567781123,55.123,45.23412,1234 MapleWay,Chicago,IL,54321
Jane,Bourne,1234567781123,77.123,45.23412,1234 MapleWay,Chicago,IL,12345
```

I have three objectives:

1. to process each row in the csv
2. to get all of the unique last names
3. be able to lookup the name associated by putting in a number

This is what I have thus far... am I on the right track? I am pretty stuck....thanks in advance.

```
        self.lastNames=[]
        self.phoneNumbers=[]
        pass

    def analyzeRow(self,row):
        #called once for every row in csv. Process row and store data in Class to be queried
        print('line[{}] = [].'.format(i,row))

    
    def getLastames(self):
        #return list of unique last names found in alphabetical order

    def phoneNumber(self,phone):
        #lookup/return name associated with provided phone number
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `df` is your dataframe:

To process each row in the csv:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('your_csv.csv', header=0, sep=',')
df.columns=['name','surname','int1', 'float1', 'float2', 'int2','neighborhood', 'city', 'state','zip_code']
```

To get all of the unique last names

```
df.surname.unique()
```

Be able to lookup the name associated by putting in a number

```
df.name[df.int1==1234567781123]
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! however, what if the requirement is that each row gets passed into that function one by one?

Comment: Pandas lookup is deprecated, but you can check this link: https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-lookup.php